# NEU like feature to find where mobs can spawn for Minecraft version 1.16.5

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

In the mod NEU there is a feature where when you press f7, it makes an overlay on all blocks so that they show whether mobs can spawn on the blocks or not.
My question was is there a mod for 1.16.5 which can do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mod called "Light Overlay", on CurseForge [here](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/light-overlay).

Comment: Thank you so much!!!